# How to call a controller from another project's controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have two projects in asp.net mvc 4. One is called "procurement" and another is called "wr". I want to call a controller in "wr" from procurement's controller.

Is it possible to launch wr's controller when procurement's controller is launched?

Comment: when "procurement" controller launched redirect to a url that call "wr" controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can just send HTTP Request:
(With model if you need)

```
  const string url= "https://youdomain/Controller/action";
   SomeModel _model = new SomeModel 
                {
                    // some properties
                };

 await _client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, _model );
```

It's best practices I think so.
Good luck